# What does it mean a contracting / expanding direction?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Generally speaking, let $A$ be a map and $v^+, v^-$ two vectors. What does it mean that $A$ is contracting along the $v^-$ direction and expanding along the $v^+$ direction? Can someone give me both a formal explanation and an intuitively one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly $v^+$ and $v^-$ are *eigenvectors* of $A$, i.e.,
$$Av^+=\lambda v^+,\quad Av^-=\mu v^-\ .$$
$A$ is *expanding* in direction $v^+$ if $|\lambda|>1$, and is *contracting* in direction $v^-$ if $|\mu|<1$.